# Different annotations for unit tests in Spring app

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am writing some unit tests and I am confused due to the different annotations in unit tests:

One of them is like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class EmployeeServiceImplTest {

    @MockBean
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeService;

    @Test
    void testFindAll() {
      //...
    }

    //...
}
```

And another is using the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public class EmployeeServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeService;

    @Test
    void testFindAll() {
      //...
    }

    //...
}
```

So, I use Java and Spring Boot for language and framework. So, which annotations should I use?

`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` or `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`,

`@MockBean` or `@Mock`,

`@Autowired` or `@InjectMocks`

Any idea regarding to these annotations?

Comment: It depends, your first example is JUnit 5, your second example is JUnit 4, and the rest depends on what mocking framework you're using at that point. And `@Autowired` is for Spring autowiring, and not directly related to testing.

Comment: I would generally prefer to use new features or annotations (prefer JUnit 5 to JUnit 4). In this scene, should I use  `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock` ? What about `@Autowired`? Should I use `@Autowired` instead of `@InjectMocks`? Or `@InjectMocks` is still valid for JUnit 5 as JUnit 4?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Any reply pls?

Comment: They're not the same thing. `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` is for when you use Mockito (for JUnit 5 with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, while `@MockBean` and `@Autowired` is for use with spring-test's `SpringExtension`. So what you should use depends on what you want or need to use use (Mockito vs spring-test)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it is more clearer. I prefer using `Mockito` and JUnit 5. Then I think I should go with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`. Is that true?

Comment: I tried @Mock, InjectMocks and ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) annotations, but not worked

Comment: Please define "but not worked".

Comment: `employeeRepository` value is null

Comment: Try placing `@InjectMocks` before `@Mock`. But anyways, now that you have decided between Mockito and Spring Test, this should be another post and a different question where you specify the problem with you unit test. This keeps the site organized.

Comment: @chris Chico, I tried with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, `@InjectMocks` at the beginning (before `@Mocks`) and `@Mock`, but still nullPointerException. Any idea?

Comment: @chris Chico, are you there?

Comment: @chris_chico Any reply please? Thanks.